# using Q paremeter in drive api results in http404

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

trying to use the query parameter in drives.list() API, but failed with wrong parameter, although I copied/paste a.google example...

```
    return gapi.client.drive.drives.list({
      "q": "name='ts'"
    })
```

what's wrong with this syntax?

Comment: Is this the only parameter you are using? The `name` parameter should be available for whoever makes the request, not having anything to do with being an admin or not. Is it a shared drive?

Comment: yes it is. and the documentation is not that.clear but having a domain access granted to the service account made it right

Answer (score 0):

well I just realized that the query parameter `name` is only available when using an admin account. not cool

Answer (score 0):

#### Solely by itself, the `name` parameter is available to anyone making the request.

Service accounts, however, are special accounts representing non-human users that need to authenticate and be authorized to access data in Google APIs.

For the purpose of making a Drive API request, just creating a service account is *not* enough.

The main purpose of granting domain-wide authority to a service account is for these accounts to be able to access data on behalf of a user in your domain as otherwise the service account acts like just another account and it is trying to access its own data from Drive.

#### Reference

- [Using OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#python);
- [Drive API Search for Files and Folders](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-files).